# Firestore document not updating effectively in my Flutter code

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, e-commerce

I am working on an app that allows customers purchase items from vendors.

After payment, vendor receives money for the item(s) in their inflow wallet.

Everything works fine when i buy only one item from the vendor and pay. But when i select multiple items from the vendor, it only updates payment for one of the items in the vendor's inflow account.

Transaction records for all items creates successfully. But the problem is with updating the inflow account with the amount.

The function updateInflow() is supposed to be called multiple times when a customer has multiple items in cart. I can't figure out what i am doing wrong here. I've check and re-checked my code.

I really need your help in figuring out this problem.

Here's my code;

```
    cartProvider!.cartList.forEach((element) {
  cartModel = CartModel.fromJson(element as Map<String, dynamic>);

          // update inflow account
    updateInflow(
      storeUid: cartModel!.storeUid,
      storeName: cartModel!.storeName,
      salesAmount: cartModel!.salesPrice,
      productQuantity: cartModel!.quantity,
      customerName: customerName,
      onlinePayment: onlinePayment,
      transactionId: transactionId,
    );});

 updateInflow({
String? storeUid,
String? storeName,
String? customerName,
salesAmount,
productQuantity,
bool? onlinePayment,
String? transactionId,}) async {

if (onlinePayment == true) {
  var _sales = salesAmount * productQuantity;

  // vendor inflow
  // should only run if buyer selects online payment
  DocumentSnapshot inflowDocument = await inflow.doc(storeUid).get();
  // create or update inflow
  if (inflowDocument.exists) {
    var inflowBalance = inflowDocument['inflowBalance'];

    var _total = inflowBalance + _sales;

    await inflow.doc(storeUid).update({
      'inflowBalance': _total,
    }).then((value) async {
      await inflow.doc(storeUid).collection('transactions').add({
        'transactionId': transactionId,
        'transactionType': 'inflow',
        'amount': _sales,
        'timestamp': DateTime.now().toString(),
        'customerName': customerName,
      });
    });
  } else {
    await inflow.doc(storeUid).set({
      'uid': storeUid,
      'accountName': storeName,
      'inflowBalance': _sales,
    }).then((value) async {
      // create transaction report
      await inflow.doc(storeUid).collection('transactions').add({
        'transactionId': transactionId,
        'transactionType': 'inflow',
        'amount': _sales,
        'timestamp': DateTime.now().toString(),
        'customerName': customerName,
      });
    });
  }
} else {
  // ignore since customer is paying cash
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So, i finally figured out a more effective way of running multiple update in a documentSnapshot at once. Dropping it here just in case someone needs it.

In my not so efficient code i used DocumentSnapshot:

```
 DocumentSnapshot inflowDocument = await inflow.doc(storeUid).get();
```

Everything worked well when i used transaction DucmentReference and then returned FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction. See below.

```
 DocumentReference documentReference =
          _firebaseServices.inflow.doc(storeUid);

      return FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        // Get the document
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
            await transaction.get(documentReference);});
```